# How to choose row name in mysql table from local variable in PHP code?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to choose row name in mysql table from a variable in Php code? For example, instead of SELECT email, I want SELECT email_2 based on my if statement like this:

```
$value == "";
if(true){
$value = email
SELECT $value from....
else{
$value = email_2
SELECT $value from....
}
```

This is my php code:

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT email from account_data_base WHERE test = ?");

$stmt->bind_param("s", $test);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a variable to select the column you want. You cannot use the statement on column names.

```
$test = 'your_value';
$column = 'email'; // column by default

if ($your_condition_is_true) {
    $column = 'email_2';
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT $column FROM account_data_base WHERE test = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $test);
```

Comment: For INSERT INTO database(username, email) VALUES, is there a way to do the same for email? Like I want to change row name from email to email_2 based on if statement? Thanks!

Comment: so it would be  INSERT INTO database(username, $column) VALUES..., correct?

Comment: $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO database(username, $column) VALUES(?, ?)"; 
Is that correct?

Comment: @KevinVuD Also :)

Comment: Ok. Let me try them all real quick and I will accept your answer. Thanks!